# Better understanding 'd' in d3.js with an example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following this example in d3.js for how to make a small-multiple choropleth map:

https://gist.github.com/armollica/6314f45890bcaaa45c808b5d2b0c602f

There's this wrapper function:

```
function ready(error, us, manufacturing) {}
```

And within it, there is:

```
function render(d) {
    var data = d.values;  //this is the manufacturing data 
    
    var context = d3.select(this).node().getContext("2d");
    
    var color = function(d) {
      console.log(d) //this is the 'US' geography json data
      if (data.has(d.id)) {
        var value = data.get(d.id).pct_change_emp;
        return value ? colorScale(value) : "#fff";
      }
      return "#fff";
    };

    // Want the maps to render sequentially. Use setTimeout to give the
    // browser a break in between drawing each map.
    window.setTimeout(function() {      
      drawMap(context, color);
    }, 500);
  }
```

I don't understand how the render function is accessing two different datasets using the same `d` variable.  Console-logging `data` is the manufacturing data, but console-logging `d` below the `var  color` declaration is the US geo-json data.

I don't see how `d` is returning different datasets here, and where that specification is happening in the code.  Everything works functionally, I'm just not understanding it.

Comment: Those `d`s are not the same. `d` in `color` function is passed by `drawMap` function. It's sad that those arguments have the same name. When this happens the one inside the inner scope shadows the outer one.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.